# Switch Branches of Subdirectories

Tags: git

From a parent directory I want to switch branches of all my subdirectories.  Is there a command for this?

```
ParentDirectory
- Sub1
- Sub2
- Sub3

cd Sub1
git checkout f1
cd ..
cd Sub2
git checkout f1
cd ..
cd Sub3
git checkout f1
cd ..
```

Comment: Wait, what?  Each of your directories houses a Git repository?

Comment: You really should provide more details because the question per se is very vague: do you really have separate *disjoint* Git repos in each subdirectory? or do you have *submodules?* or may be it's a single repository but you're looking for something like switching a branch of a subtirectory *like you would do that in Subversion?* You see, there's too much left to guess, so people get confused, start fighting in comments etc. Please be precise.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash, from top level directory

```
for d in */ ; do
    git checkout "$d"
done
```

If you're using windows cmd:

```
For /D %G IN (*) do git checkout %G
```

Comment: You're not technically wrong, but the very fact that this seems atypical for a Git repository leads me to believe that there is something *else* amiss here.

Comment: @Makoto Would you please stop jumping on and down voting everything I post? Particiularly if you agree this is techically correct.
If you have multiple git repositories, say in an eclipse workspace and you wanted to switch all of them at once that would be a perfectly valid use case and my solution would work.

Comment: No, not necessarily...you'd probably want to use submodule-based commands if they were truly submodules...  Again, I said that you're technically correct (at least in the mechanical sense), but I still sense that this isn't the correct solution to the actual *problem*.

Comment: @Makoto What you're saying is you don't like the solution. That's fine. By all means provide a better one or one you like better if you have one. Otherwise stop stomping on working solutions. Your idea and the other answer provided now only work for submodules.

Comment: I'd need more information from the OP to truly guide them in a suitable direction...I mean, it *could* be the case that they are describing submodules; at that point I'd defer to VonC's answer, or they could be describing something else.  But I don't know that for sure.  I maintain that your solution only addresses the logically mechanical aspect of it.  If this truly is a project that uses submodules, this could make things *worse*.  Until it's demonstrated by the OP otherwise, I don't agree with this solution, and I personally need more info before I could come up with my own.

Comment: Scripting the solution using the shell is perfectly valid. The solution I provided makes no assumptions and does EXACTLY what the OP has asked to do. If you want to provide a warning about circumstances under which the OP might not in fact want to do what he has explicitly asked to do, go ahead, but that does not affect the validity of the solution.

Comment: That's a working answer to the question for sure.. Don't understand what's the problem here.

Comment: @HarishVed, please see my comment to the original post: the question might be subtler than it appears (due to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)).

Answer (score 0):

If your subfolders are all **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, then you can use [`git submodule foreach`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) (even `git submodule foreach --recursive` if your submodules include submodules)

```
git submodule foreach git checkout -b newBranch
```